# Is it possible to add "somewhere" a `before(:each)` hook so that all spec file can run it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, hook

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and rspec-rails-2.8.1. In order to make my spec files *DRY* (Don't Repeat Yourself) and to seed the `test` database I would like to run a `before(:each)` hook for all those spec files. That is, in all my spec files I have the following code:

```
describe 'test description' do
  before(:each) do
    load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
  end

  ...
end
```

**Is it possible to add "somewhere" that `before(:each)` hook so that all spec files can run it?** *What do you advice?*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  #your other config

  config.before(:each) do
    #your code here
  end
end
```

There is much configuration available. For instance: `config.before(:each, :type => [:routing, :controller, :request])`

You can even create your own tags and associate code to it:

```
config.around :each, unobstrusive: true do |example|
  Capybara.current_driver = :rack_test 
  example.run
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add before/after hooks in your `Rspec.configure` block, usually in your spec_helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    ...
  end
end
```