# How can I set http header for all capybara features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I use rspec, capybara. I set locale from http header as in bellow

```
  before_filter :set_locale

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end

  def set_locale
    return I18n.locale = current_user.locale if user_signed_in?
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale
  end
```

When I run my feature test I get error 'undefined method `scan` for NilClass'. 
Apparently capybara don't set http headers.

How I can set http header for all my features or avoid this by another way?

Comment: maybe this could inspire you: https://gist.github.com/raul/717819

Answer (score 13):

depending on your browser driver, you can set headers globally like this:

```
  Capybara.current_session.driver.headers = { 'Accept-Language' => 'de' }
  Capybara.current_session.driver.header('Accept-Language', 'de')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to 'stick' to all features and scenarios. Any idea why?

Comment: In `spec_helper.rb` which is included in every feature file.

Comment: try adding it into before :each block in the configuration

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. For future reference, here is the [rspec syntax for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958110/is-it-possible-to-add-somewhere-a-beforeeach-hook-so-that-all-spec-file-c#answer-9958232).

Comment: How to do it for one test though?

Comment: you put it into a around block in your spec and unset the headers afterwards

Comment: It's probably worth using `current_driver.add_header(name, value)` instead of `headers =` where possible (e.g. Poltergeist) to avoid risk of overriding the existing headers.

Answer (score 9):

You can set your headers like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    page.driver.header 'Accept-Language', 'de'
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#non-standard-driver-methods

> header: set the given HTTP header for subsequent requests
>
> page.driver.header 'Referer', 'https://www.thoughtbot.com'

Comment: You can only be certain that this works if you use the WebKit driver.