# Rails: Count number of test cases in an application without running the tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, grep

Is there any way to count number of test cases written in an application. Mainly the `<app-root>/test` and `<app-root>/rspec`.

I guess this can be done with `grep`

Comment: What testing system? `rspec` or `test/unit` style? If they're all methods called `test_...` you can inspect each of your test classes. Keep in mind `grep` will find all tests, but some might be walled off and not run due to surrounding code.

Comment: Getting a  count of the files or the number of `it` blocks or methods defined in test classes can possibly be done but tells you nothing about the quality of the test suite. Additionally if you factor in stuff like the minitest BDD syntax its actually quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: For RSpec, you could skip all the tests using a before block? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9958233/1612744.